# Matplolib using lists making step graphs

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib

I'm having a problem, where I can't do a step graph of 2 lists I have, in which I need list `x` to be the x values, in which each `x[j]` value will add with `x[j+1]` value for each step.

```
x = [10, 10, 20, 20, 200, 800, 800, 800, 900, 1800, 2000, 600, 1500, 1800, 500, 800, 8000]

y = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 18.47, 18.47, 18.47, 18.47, 19.23, 19.23, 19.23, 27.88, 27.88, 27.88]
```

`y` needs to be in this order, but I need to make a step graph out of this using matplotlib. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you looking for `numpy.cumsum` or something like `x = [sum(p) for p in zip(x, x[1:])]`?

Comment: numpy.cumsum solved my problems, thanks ! :)

Comment: @Bill you could post your comment as an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `numpy.cumsum`.  For example:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: x = range(1, 5)
In [3]: x
Out[3]: [1, 2, 3, 4]
In [4]: y = np.cumsum(x)
In [5]: y
Out[5]: [1, 3, 6, 10]
```